# Getting Error 2337 while installing SQL Server 2014 on Windows 10

Tags: sql-server

Can someone please help me, I am stuck with an error message saying "The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2337" When I click on more details, It shows the source of the error is file called setup.rll

The installation fails at the "Installation Progress" level which is the second last step of the of the installation steps

I have tried researching and some sites suggest that I go to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\SQLServer2014 and rename the setup.rll file. But when I navigate to this location The Setup Bootstrap does not contain the SQLServer2014 folder.

The strange thing is that I was able to install SQL Server on another 2 other machines. I just dont know what is wrong with my machine.

Thank you in advance for your brilliant replies.

Comment: Possible answer: Need extract, do NOT mount http://serverfault.com/a/348064/145950